# Are there recommended ways to structure multiple JSON schemas?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I just wrote my first JSON schemas, great! However, I am now looking at how to structure multiple JSON schemas, both during development and later how to host them. There seems to be very limited guidance on this.

Of course, I looked up the official json-schema.org documentation [on how to structure a complex scheme](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html), and even got *something* to work. I now have three schemas, organized during development in a folder structure as follows:

```
json-schemas
  - /common
    - /common-schemas.json
  - /data
    - /data-schemas.json
    - /DataStreamServiceRequest
      - /DataStreamServiceRequest-schema.json
```

Out of these three, only [`DataStreamServiceRequest-schema.json`](https://github.com/cph-cachet/carp.core-kotlin/pull/351/files#diff-941c69ff33eb531a3e36c044e9047ad04c70aebe015d4e89e8e7900c84e6ef92) contains a *single* schema (it is a schema for all possible requests to an application service endpoint). It refers to types defined in [`data-schemas.json`](https://github.com/cph-cachet/carp.core-kotlin/pull/351/files#diff-e867382e7b63d138c286c1e32c3b8fa183ed42e35d17d81f2f7bfa3104596507) and [`common-schemas.json`](https://github.com/cph-cachet/carp.core-kotlin/pull/351/files#diff-e0e7cb3f7ab22e7ac10f66a57f1465a3cf5cc2a40f11c8e31b4dcee269048b20) by using relative references. The intent here was to have all types for a single subsystem (e.g., `data`) available in one file.

I assigned all three `.json` files with an `$id` containing the absolute URI, corresponding to the directory they are in.

For example, here is `common-schemas.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "$id": "https://carp.cachet.dk/schemas/common",
  "NamespacedId": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^([a-z_0-9]+\\.?)+[a-z_0-9]$"
  }
}
```

And, from `data-schemas.json`, I refer to `NamespacedId` in `common-schemas.json` using:

```
"dataType": { "$ref": "common#/NamespacedId" }
```

I'm glad this works, but, is this recommended? Am I overlooking something fundamental structuring my schemas as follows? Is there any particular reason to prefer "one schema per type"? Is there an idiomatic structure I am overlooking, e.g., an equivalent to Java's file location corresponding to namespace?

If there isn't (I would argue in Java there is) that would also constitute an answer.

Perhaps additional relevant context: I'm using [networknt/json-schema-validator](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator), and for development/testing purposes, it is very convenient to not have too many absolute URIs. I [need to map each URI to a local file](https://github.com/cph-cachet/carp.core-kotlin/pull/351/files#diff-6b36a42fcbcddff4df1ed0632a62ec8c9d0091d37b16a86eb6dc948f81c56003R15) when initializing the validator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @Ether said, there's no one right answer, but here are the guidelines I use.

The most important guide post is to treat your schemas like you would any other code in your system. Generally, that means each "thing" that you are describing ("Person", "Product", "Address", etc) should have it's own schema.

Definitions (`$defs`) should only be referenced (`$ref`) from within the same schema. Use definitions to improve readability or reduce duplication within a schema. Any reference to an external schema should not have a JSON Pointer URI fragment (e.g., the `#/$defs/NamespacedId` fragment you use). If you need to reference a definition in an external schema, it's probably a sign it should be in it's own schema.

An exception to this might be if you have a bunch of tiny schemas you want to put in a "common.schema.json" schema. In this case, all of your schemas should be defined as definitions, but have an anchor `$anchor`. It needs to be a definition so you can use standard tools to verify that your schemas are valid. Using an anchor allows you to reference it easier, but more importantly, it's a signal that some external schema might be depending on it. Definitions without an anchor are effectively private to the schema and definitions with an anchor are effectively public. You can freely refactor unanchored definitions, but you have to be wary of breaking other schemas if you refactor anchored definitions.

Don't use `$id`s. When a schema doesn't have an `$id`, it's identified by the URI that was used to retrieve the schema. That can be a file URI (`file:///path/to/schemas/person.schema.json`). Then all of your references can be relative meaning there are no absolute URIs in your schemas and you don't need configuration to map `https` URIs to file locations. Unfortunately, not all implementations support file based retrieval or even retrieval URI identification, so this isn't always possible.

Organize your schemas however makes sense. Follow the same instincts and guidelines you would for any other code. If you have to use `$id`s, make sure the path matches the path on the file system (Ex `https://example.com/schemas/person` => `file:///local/path/to/app/schemas/person.schema.json`). This just makes it easier to find schemas you're looking for.

Comment: _"Definitions without an anchor are effectively private to the schema and definitions with an anchor are effectively public."_ This is one such "convention" I was after I was unaware about. It makes sense, and the public/private analogy holds. Thank you for an excellent answer! :)

Comment: While waiting for an answer, I also discovered the benefits of: (1) having one file per schema, matching the path of the `$id`s (so I removed the JSON Pointer URIs). This allowed me to inject a simple proxy into the URI retrieval of [the library I am using](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator), replacing all `https://my-namespace` requests with `file:`, so no individual mapping needed.

Comment: (2) including `.json` in the `$id` (not something you mentioned, but find meaningful now.  Rather than including `json` somewhere in the namespace, the `.json` file extension already provides that information. Furthermore, IntelliJ now provides meaningful information on whether the files exist, assuming you also adopt your advice #1.

Comment: Lastly, it is interesting your advice to not use `$id` goes [counter that of the documentation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#id). _But_, indeed, by adopting #1 and #2, I could remove the URI mapper proxy. For development purposes, and DRY, this is excellent. The advice of including `$id` from the documentation is still sound, but makes more sense when _publishing_ schemas, and I guess is something which a bundler can/should do.

Comment: Another consideration not including an `$id` during dev. This allows to easily include a _version_ as part of publishing.

Comment: Yes, I think the spec oversteps by suggesting all schemas should have an `$id`. There are many contexts where that isn't the best approach. I actually wrote that page of the documentation. I left that in there because the spec says it, but I personally don't think it's a good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the only tip that works after searching online for over an hour!

Comment: With all that said, I don't agree with the advice to not use `$id`. Note, that `$id` you write in any schema still does not have to be an absolute-URI. It could still be a relative reference, but, for example, with an absolute path. In this case, you could have all your id's relative. But the Base URI of the schema(s) in general will be determined either by retrieaval, or you could specify it when bundling all schemas into a single one.

Comment: The reason I suggest not using `$id` is that it creates two competing ways to identify the schema. The location of the schema is always sufficient for identification. Also including `$id` means there are two ways to identify a schema that could get out of sync. Using relative `$id`s doesn't solve that problem. If you rename the file, you have to make sure to rename the `$id` the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Like code organization, there is no one right answer. If you are going to reuse a particular schema in a number of different environments, putting it in a separate file can make sense. But if you're only going to use it in one place, it may be more convenient to put it under a `$defs` in the same file. You could even give that schema a nicer name to reference it, via `$anchor`.

Comment: I understood the use of `$defs`. For my question, assume I _do_ want to split schemas across files. My question was whether there is some convention (e.g. like in Java namespaces correspond to file locations) on where to place them, and how/which `$id` to assign. Or, is it common to for example bundle multiple schemas for one microservice in one file and require selecting schemas through fragments (as I do now), or should these be subschemas?