# What is the difference between $id and $anchor?

Tags: jsonschema

The following schema uses `$id` to provide a position-independent way of identifying the two subschemas:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
   "$id": "http://www.example.com/schema",
   "$defs": {
        "schema1": {
            "$id": "insect",
            "type": "string", 
            "enum": ["beetle", "grasshopper"]
        },
        "schema2": {
            "$id": "fruit",
            "type": "string", 
            "enum": ["orange", "apple"]
        }
   },
   "$ref": "insect"
}
```

And this schema constrains instances to the exact same degree, using `$anchor`:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
   "$id": "http://www.example.com/schema",
   "$defs": {
        "schema1": {
            "$anchor": "insect",
            "type": "string", 
            "enum": ["beetle", "grasshopper"]
        },
        "schema2": {
            "$anchor": "fruit",
            "type": "string", 
            "enum": ["orange", "apple"]
        }
   },
   "$ref": "insect"
}
```

So what's the difference between `$id` and `$anchor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$anchor` is a plain string that identifies a location within schema document. It's used in the fragment (`#`) part of a `$ref` URI. It's an alternative to the JSON Pointer syntax you normally see in references (`#/$defs/schema1` == `#insect`). So, your second schema isn't correct. It's missing the `#` before "insect" in the `$ref`.

`$id` is a lot more complicated. It's a URI that identifies a schema resource. The schema can be referenced by that URI. `$id` can also appear within a schema like in your first example. In that case, the schema where the `$id` is located is considered an embedded schema. It's treated as it's own independent schema resource separate from the parent schema it's embedded in. The URI for `$id` in embedded schemas can be resolved against the `$id` of the parent schema to get the full URI that identifies the embedded schema. So, the identifier for the schema with `"$id": "insect"` is actually, `http://example.com/insect`. `"$ref": "insect"` matches that schema because it's also resolved against the `$id` of the schema.

Generally, embedded schemas are only used to bundle schemas that are developed separately, but need to be distributed as a single schema for some reason. So, you wouldn't use it when writing a schema, but it may be present after a build step.

Since `$id` identifies a schema and `$anchor` identifies a location within a schema, you occasionally might use both together to reference what you need. For example, you could reference `http://example.com/schema#insect` to get the "insect" schema. `http://example.com/schema` is defined by `$id` and `#insect` is defined by `$anchor`.

You might find these useful.

- https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html
- [Are there recommended ways to structure multiple JSON schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807993/are-there-recommended-ways-to-structure-multiple-json-schemas/70826779#70826779)

Comment: "So, your second schema isn't correct. It's missing the # before "insect" in the $ref." But it works fine, without the #, in your online Hyperjump validation tool. (I tested both of the above schemas using your tool) Should your tool have generated an error since I didn't have # before insect?

Comment: I'm guessing that you wrote the first schema (with `$id`) then changed it to the second schema (with `$anchor`). How schema retrieval works in JSON Schema is a bit awkward. Anything you give it with an `$id` creates a persistent mapping to that schema. So, your first schema created three mappings: `https://example.com/schema`, `http://example.com/insect`, and `http://example.com/fruit`. The "insect" and "fruit" mappings don't go away because you removed the `$id`s. They'll remain until you remap them somehow with another `$id`.

Comment: So, the reference in the second schema isn't resolving to the "insect" anchor, it's resolving to the most recent schema that was mapped to `http://example.com/insect`, even though that schema has since been removed. There's probably something I can do to reset the mappings in the online tool to avoid confusion in that context, but my general advice remains, avoid using `$id`. You don't need it. It's just a foot gun.

Comment: Do I correctly understand your recommendations: Use $id to name a schema or subschema. Use $anchor to provide a position-independent way to reference a schema (subschema). Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite. I recommend you don't use `$id` in sub-schemas. If the sub-schema needs it's own identifier, then it should be defined separately in it's own schema. I actually don't recommend using `$id` for root schemas either. There's almost always a natural identifier for the schema and it's better to use that if the implementation supports it. Most of the time the natural identifier is a `file:` URI representing the path of the schema file on the filesystem. The online tool is one of the rare cases where there isn't a natural identifier and using `$id` for root schemas is necessary.