# Is the use of $id in subschemas a security risk?

Tags: jsonschema

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931216/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-anchor) Stack Overflow post I give an example of identifying a subschema using `$id` and then later replacing the `$id` with `$anchor`. Despite an incorrect `$anchor` value, the validator said that the schema was valid. Why? In his (excellent) answer @Jason Desrosiers explains (paraphrasing): "*`$id` creates a persistent mapping to a schema. The mapping doesn't go away even when you remove the `$id`.*"

Two questions:

1. Would you point me to the portion of the JSON Schema specification that talks about this, *i.e.*, the portion of the spec that talks about `$id` mappings persisting even when the `$id` is removed?
2. Is the use of `$id` in subschemas a security risk? It seems plausible that the "`$id` mapping persistence" behavior could be exploited to do bad things. (Analogous to the security risk of a browser that persists a password that was entered on a web page even when the web page is exited.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would you point me to the portion of the JSON Schema specification that talks about this, i.e., the portion of the spec that talks about `$id` mappings persisting even when the `$id` is removed?

The spec doesn't talk about this directly. JSON Schema expects users to [load their schemas](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#name-loading-a-schema) into the implementation to make them available to be referenced for other schemas. While technically, it doesn't say how long those schemas should remain available, there's no concept of a session or unloading mappings stated or implied in the spec, so I think most of the time that means the schemas you load stay available until they get unloaded or replaced somehow although the spec doesn't mention a concept of unloading or replacing mappings.

> Is the use of `$id` in subschemas a security risk? It seems plausible that the "`$id` mapping persistence" behavior could be exploited to do bad things. (Analogous to the security risk of a browser that persists a password that was entered on a web page even when the web page is exited.)

I'm glad you asked this because this never occurred to me and I think you might be right. I'm going to refrain from discussing specific exploits in public, but I'll bring this up in private with the JSON Schema team.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that implementations are encouraged to error when encountering multiple schemas with the same `$id` value.

Specifically, [section 9.1.2](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#section-9.1.2) states:

> A schema MAY (and likely will) have multiple URIs, but there is no way for a URI to identify more than one schema. **When multiple schemas try to identify as the same URI, validators SHOULD raise an error condition.**

This isn't a hard requirement, but it is a strong encouragement for a behavior that would prevent someone registering a new schema against a known `$id` value.

> It seems plausible that the "`$id` mapping persistence" behavior could be exploited to do bad things.

The spec doesn't say anything about persistence of a map.  My implementation isolates individual validations by default, so there is no persistence between validations.

FWIW, [Jason's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931216/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-anchor#comment135622631_76931969) that contains the text you quoted isn't right.  This is an implementation-defined behavior because the spec is silent about it.

This (in the next comment)

> So, the reference in the second schema isn't resolving to the "insect" anchor, it's resolving to the most recent schema that was mapped to http://example.com/insect, even though that schema has since been removed.

is likely correct *for the implementation that that user is using*, but it's not in general.  I would say that such retention behavior comes down to poor design.

Aside from any security implications (which we're still discussing), it wouldn't support concurrent validations.  If you have a web API where people can submit their own schemas, and two users both submit `$id: https://example.com/schema` because they don't want to think of anything better, without isolation, whosever call reaches the server second SHOULD result in an error (because of the spec line above).  With isolation, they can both proceed.